# Nested and sequential for-loop complexity

Tags: for-loop, time-complexity, big-o, discrete-mathematics, code-complexity

I'm doing something really close to this code :

```
for(int k=0; k<n; k++) {            // n
    for(int a=0; a<k; a++) {        // n/2 -> n (watch the a<k)
        ...                         // c
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {        // n
        for(int a=0; a<i; a++) {    // n/2 -> n (watch the a<i)
            ...                     // c
        }
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {    //n
            ...                     //c
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to find out is the complexity... I found O(n^3) but I don't want to "accept" this answer.. Basically if I remove the 2 for(a) loop it would be the same complexity ?

But in reality those codes wont have the same execution time and probably wont be that close.. Why is it still O(n^3) :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will still be O(n^3) after removal of the the for(a)'s.

https://www.interviewcake.com/article/java/big-o-notation-time-and-space-complexity

Also, [Big O notation with nested for loops and single for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886424/big-o-notation-with-nested-for-loops-and-single-for-loop/39886634#39886634)